# dedicated server virtualization, xen or openvz?

Tags: virtualization, xen, openvz

I am putting a new server in a datacenter for company use and my company website. I use a lot of VPS accounts and in that world the choices are xen or openvz. I will be using virtualization on my dedicated server. It is difficult to find any information comparing the platforms outside of the VPS service context. We will not be renting out VPS accounts, we only wish to run isolated environments, and avoid the cost of multiple servers. I understand the basic difference of os level virtualization vs. hypervisor paravirtualization. It seems that most big companies are using xen, but in my experience openvz can achive better performance, due to the pooled resources, as many containers are likely to be idle. Does anyone have any experience with openvz or xen in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any other people than people who have access to the host using the VPS?

```
If yes: 
   Xen
else:
   openvz
```

One of the reasons for this is that you might end up rebooting a server. Unfortunately in OpenVZ this command doesn't work and results in a shut down server that needs to be booted from the host. Also have a look at LXC, it's the same as OpenVZ but doesn't use an as heavily patched kernel.

Comment: thanks!  No one else will need to reboot the host or containers.  The main reason for virtualization is to isolate environments in case of a security breach.  Also to solve versioning issues.  I will look into LXC.  Would there be any other reasons that I should prefer Xen?

Comment: Not that I can think off, I use LXC instead of Xen/KVM if it's just about isolation.

Comment: Based on some googling it seems LXC is not very secure, in that a compromised container could lead to a compromised host.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'll gladly take a look at those, can you link me?

Comment: http://berrange.com/posts/2011/09/27/getting-started-with-lxc-using-libvirt/
search the page for the word "secure"

Comment: http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2011/08/anybody-using-lxc-or-openvz-in.html
second post in comments section

Comment: I actually wasn't aware of this, maybe it's better to go with OpenVZ then. I haven't seen any posts about people being able to break out of an OpenVZ container. Or check this article by IBM that explains how you can still secure them: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-lxc-security/

Comment: I agree with this decision tree. The reboots are a good way of illustrating the use case, but I must clarify that one will only need to reboot the host (hardware node) when upgrading the kernel or if there was some kernel-level or hardware-level problem. Otherwise OpenVZ containers can be rebooted individually.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favorite is still XEN. We decided to use it in 2007, since it was the best of breed back then with regards to performance and resource (CPU-overhead) usage.

We are using it with Linux in Dom0 and (mostly) Linux in PV-mode as DomUs.

If you need to run different Kernel Versions or different Linux distributions XEN is better - since you have the full Kernel in your VM.

If going for XEN have a look at Oracle VM, SLES11 SP2 or Citrix. It depends on your licensing needs which is the most cost-effective solution for you.

If you are in a pure Linux environment, KVM might be another possible solution nowadays (available in Debian, Ubuntu LTS, RedHat, SLES, ...).

Comment: KVM in a "pure linux environment". KVM runs W2k8 R2 pretty good.

Comment: Well - SLES11 runs on Hyper-V, too. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

See it for yourself: http://openvz.org/Performance

Executive summary: for pure computational cases there is no or little difference. For any other task the difference can be up to few times (in OpenVZ favor).

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.